# Error:Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals

Tags: matlab

I am currently running into a problem with this error, everything was fine before I added this section of code in

```
    a=squeeze(b(x1,y1,z1,:));
    a_min = min(a);
    a_max = max(a);
    if a_max == 0 continue, end;
    a = (a - a_min)/a_max;
```

After I add this in, there were problem and this error start to pop up.
"a" is a 156x1 matrix ranging from negative value to 2.2.
The numbers from "a" are used to change the numbers in the value portion of HSV colormap.

b is a 4d matrix where the last portion is time value, x1,y1,z1 are the 3d coordinate of a point.

Comment: You need to provide proper code. No one would know "ae_min" came from and what other variables mean.

Comment: sorry the ae_min is a typo, it is just a_min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place you are using indices is with the `b(x1,y1,z1,;)`call.

Make sure these are integer values: i.e. maybe you just need to do

`b(round(x1),round(y1),round(z1),:)`

if your coordinate is with decimals.

Comment: thanks, that was just the problem, some the value are decimal

Answer (score 1):

Are `x1,y1` and `z1` all positive and **integer**? Judging from the error, this is a problem. Negative numbers cannot be used as indices for a matrix in matlab/octave.

You can check if this code works

```
a=squeeze(b(abs(round(x1)),abs(round(y1)),abs(round(z1)),:));
a_min = min(a);
a_max = max(a);
if a_max == 0 continue, end;
a = (a - a_min)/a_max;
```

if there is no error, the problem is indeed with `x1,y1,z1` values, and you should inspect the rest of your code to find a bug.

Comment: yes they are non-negative
    a_min = min(a);
    a_max = max(a);
    if a_max == 0 continue, end;
    a = (a - a_min)/a_max;
this portion of the code is to ensure the numbers are non-negative and are all between 0-1 so it can be use as value for the hsv colormap

Comment: I am not asking about "a" values, but about your indices - `x1`, `y1` and `z1`, I think that some of them are negative numbers, code is not checking it.